# CSS check not focus

Tags: css, radio-button, checked

How do I get the animation to occur on `:check` of `radio` button instead of `:focus`?

I tried `.radio-button:checked ~ .item-tile` and `input[type=radio]:checked + .item-tile` both not working.

```css
.item .radio-button:focus+.item-tile {
  border: 2px solid #079ad9;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.item-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item-tile {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.item-tile label {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 0;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 5px;
}

.icon {
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
}

.item .radio-button {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item .item-tile {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease, -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrap">
    <div class="item">
      <input id="blue" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:blue;">
        </div>
        <label for="blue" class="item-tile-label"><text class="item-text">Blue</text></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input id="elephant" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:red;">
        </div>
        <label for="elephant" class="item-tile-label"><text class="item-text">Elephant</text></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be looking for `.item .radio-button:checked + .item-tile`:

```css
.item .radio-button:checked + .item-tile {
  border: 2px solid #079ad9;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.item-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item-tile {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.item-tile label {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 0;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 5px;
}

.icon {
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
}

.item .radio-button {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item .item-tile {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease, -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrap">
    <div class="item">
      <input id="blue" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:blue;">
        </div>
        <label for="blue" class="item-tile-label"><text class="item-text">Blue</text></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input id="elephant" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio" />
      <div class="item-tile">
        <div class="icon" style="background-color:red;">
        </div>
        <label for="elephant" class="item-tile-label"><text class="item-text">Elephant</text></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```